# Explanation of "effective type"?

Tags: c

I'm reading the C specification, which states in [6.5 Expressions](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.html)

> The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any. If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value.

Can anyone explain what this means? I've got a vague feeling that it has to do with pointers and `malloc()`, but that's as far as I can get without help from a lawyer...

Update based on answer: Can I safely do this?

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    int *x = malloc(1000);
    *x = 10;
    printf("%d\n", *x);

    struct point *p = x;
    p->x = 5;
    p->y = 10;
    printf("%d %d\n", p->x, p->y);
}
```

I'm getting a warning, but it works in my case. Is it guaranteed to work?

Comment: anyone else think language lawyer tag might be appropriate here, since it's directly asking about a quote from the standard?

Comment: Could you edit/comment to indicate which section of the standard this is from?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: edited

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso   [6.5.17](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you declare a variable of a given type, it refers to an underlying object of that type, so the object's effective type is the type of the associated variable.

Where things get a little fuzzy is when `malloc` comes into play.  Memory returned from `malloc` has no effective type.  For example:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes in size, `x` now points to 4 bytes of memory with no effective type.  This memory gets an effective type when assigned to:

```
*x = 123;
```

Now those bytes have an effective type of `int`.

In the case of your example, you allocate 1000 bytes, and initially these bytes have no effective type.

```
*x = 10;
```

This makes the first `sizeof(int)` bytes an object of type `int`.

```
struct point *p = x;
```

This *should* have a cast, but in the end it's OK because the first member of `struct point` has type `int`, and a pointer to a struct points to its first member.

```
p->x = 5;
```

This is therefore safe, because `&p->x` points to an object of type `int`, which matches the type of the lvalue `p->x`.

```
p->y = 10;
```

This is also safe, because the bytes pointed to by `&p->y` do not yet have an effective type, and the assignment causes the next `sizeof(int)` bytes to be an object of type `int`.

Comment: however, if after that `char *p = x; p = "hello"` it seems to print fine (with a warning). Same for a struct. What's happening?

Comment: @blue_note C lets you convert between any pointer types automatically, which if I understand correctly is what you're seeing there.

Comment: @blue_note you’re not changing the memory returned from `malloc`.  You’re changing `p` to point to a string constant instead.  The second assignment overwrites the result of the first.

Comment: @dbush: ok, string literal was a bad example. But, If I had allocated enough memory (eg `malloc(10000)`), would it be safe to do the struct assignment, or any other assignment??

Comment: @blue_note what do you mean by “the struct assignment”?  Please give a specific example, and update your question as such.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: C does not let you convert between any pointer types automatically. The standard does not define conversions between pointers to objects and pointers to functions at all. Pointers to objects may be converted explicitly, as with casts, with some limitations and rules about the consequences. Automatic (implicit) conversions are limited, such as for adding qualifiers. The assignment of an `int *` to a `char *` is a constraint violation (C 2018 6.5.16.1 1).

Comment: @EricPostpischil isn’t there an exception for conversion to a `char *`?

Comment: @blue_note I've updated my answer to address your example.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right about pointers to objects and function pointers. You don't need an explicit cast to convert between pointers to objects however. Section 6.3.2.3 covers implicit conversions involving pointers, in particular 6.3.2.3.7 says: (1/3)

Comment: "A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object." (2/3)

Comment: @dbush: No, not in the constraints for assignment. Assignment allows conversion to or from `void *` and adding qualifiers, but the pointer types must otherwise be compatible. The rules about using character pointers are to allow accessing the raw bytes of objects, but that is after explicit conversion (or two implicit conversions using `void *` as an intermediary).

Comment: So you're right about there being limitations on converting between pointers, but you don't seem to need an explicit cast. And from the section I quoted, it seems like converting to a `char *` is always acceptable. Maybe I'm missing a piece of the standard though. (3/3)

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: “May be converted” means a pointer **may** be converted. It does not mean there is an automatic conversion. And the paragraph I cited **explicitly** constrains the allowed types for assignment. Assigning an `int *` to a `char *` **violates the constraints**.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: Re “Section 6.3.2.3 covers implicit conversions involving pointers…”: No, it does not; that clause does not say it is about implicit conversions. It is about conversions.